# How to create a hill climbing algorithm

Tags: python, string, algorithm, random, hill-climbing

I have been following a book for learning python, and the book has one of the following challenge:

> Self Check
>
> Here’s a self check that really covers everything so far. You may have
>   heard of the infinite monkey theorem? The theorem states that a monkey
>   hitting keys at random on a typewriter keyboard for an infinite amount
>   of time will almost surely type a given text, such as the complete
>   works of William Shakespeare. Well, suppose we replace a monkey with a
>   Python function. How long do you think it would take for a Python
>   function to generate just one sentence of Shakespeare? The sentence
>   we’ll shoot for is: “methinks it is like a weasel”
>
> You’re not going to want to run this one in the browser, so fire up
>   your favorite Python IDE. The way we’ll simulate this is to write a
>   function that generates a string that is 28 characters long by
>   choosing random letters from the 26 letters in the alphabet plus the
>   space. We’ll write another function that will score each generated
>   string by comparing the randomly generated string to the goal.
>
> A third function will repeatedly call generate and score, then if 100%
>   of the letters are correct we are done. If the letters are not correct
>   then we will generate a whole new string.To make it easier to follow
>   your program’s progress this third function should print out the best
>   string generated so far and its score every 1000 tries.

I was able to implement this part of the challenge, with the following code:
(I am new to python)

```
import random
target = 'methinks it is like a weasel'
target_len = 28

def string_generate(strlen):
 alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ' #26 letters of the alphabet + space
 res = ''
 for i in range(strlen):
  res += alphabet[random.randrange(27)]

 return res

def score_check(target,strlen):
 score = 0
 res = string_generate(strlen)
 for i in range(strlen):
  if res[i] == target[i]:
   score += 1
 return score, res

def progress_check():
 counter = 0
 score = 0
 res = ''
 while score != 28:
  score_temp, res_temp = score_check(target, target_len)
  counter += 1
  if score_temp > score:
   score, res = score_temp, res_temp
   print(res, score)
  else:
   score, res = score, res

 return res, score

progress_check()
```

It then have the following extra challenge:

Self Check Challenge

> See if you can improve upon the program in the self check by keeping
>   letters that are correct and only modifying one character in the best
>   string so far. This is a type of algorithm in the class of ‘hill
>   climbing’ algorithms, that is we only keep the result if it is better
>   than the previous one.

However, I am not able to figure out what this hill climbing algorithim is, and how I would implement it into my existing piece of code.

Please explain how to implement this hill climbing algorithm, thank you all so much!

Comment: Code improvements belong on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Simple but maybe inefficient method: After you have generated your first random string choose randomly a character position, check if this character is already the right one in right place. If so, choose again until you find a wrong one. Choose randomly a letter from alphabet and set it at this position in the generated string. Repeat  until all characters match.

Comment: In `score_check()` you can "erase" non matching chars in `target`. Then in `string_generate()`, only replace the erased letters.

Comment: @GrantGarrison Oh ok then if an answer can provide a way to implement a so called 'hill climbing' algorithm, that will be enough for me, thanks!

Comment: @GrantGarrison Code improvements do, but recommendations for how to write code does not. (i.e. answering OP's question of how to write a hill climbing algorithm).

Comment: @rluo Since you're learning python, you may choose to submit completed working code (such as the top of your question, up to but not including "It then have the following...") to Code Review.  The people there will give constructive criticism on how you could improve your code.  (The big thing I would mention is - don't make a function called "score_check" call "string_generate" - do what the function says.  "score_check" should have the generated string passed to it.)  The bottom part of your question is perfect for Stack Overflow, and it's great that you provided code to us...

Comment: ... so we have a basis to know what answer to give you.  Honestly, I don't see such well-written questions from a new Stack Overflow user very often.  Good job.